# Why I can not find shared folder in my pc?

Tags: windows-10, shared-folders

When I enter my computer address in the network, it shows me some shared folders.
But when I search for these folders on my computer, I do not find them.

Please guide me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open a Powershell and type Get-SmbShare
or Open a DOS prompt and type Net share
Theses 2 commands will display the shares on your computer, with another information : Path or Resource on your local drive.
With this info, you could browse to this shared folders.
Nota : The Share name and the folder Name could be different.
Regards
Olivier

Comment: Some folders do not exist in the desired path.